# Silverlight UI culture

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I have a date column in a datagrid in my silverlight App. I need the time to be displayed in 24 hr format. To achieve this I have modified the UI culture in Application_Startup event like this:

```
    CultureInfo cinf = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
    DateTimeFormatInfo f = cinf.DateTimeFormat.Clone() as DateTimeFormatInfo;
    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo df = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
    string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    f.FullDateTimePattern = format;
    cinf.DateTimeFormat = f;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cinf;
```

But the UI always picks up the datatime format specified in my regional settings on my OS.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `CurrentCulture` as well, that is:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cinf;
```

Comment: Yes I have tried setting both CurrentCulture & CurrentUICulture but still the UI renders with the 12 hr format. Whats interesting is that when I put a break point on view model class, the format shows up as 24 hr format. !!!

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to define ther required formatting on the binding itself? Something like:-

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="SomeDate" Binding="{Binding SomeDate, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}}" />
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is that the `CultureInfo` used by controls loaded by Xaml is defined by the `Language` property of control loading the Xaml.  I don't think there is a way to provide a custom `CultureInfo` in this scenario.

Comment: I have an absolute requirement that I return a DateTime Object, I cannot use a binding converter that returns a string. I have filters on each column that depend on the datatype of the column. I have tried the "Language" property in the XAML and the culture is reflected based on the Language that I set, but even the settings of that language are picked up from the OS settings??...any other ways to override this??

Comment: @avinash: Normally one does filtering via an implementation of `ICollectionView`, this would apply to the incoming set of objects before any binding has occured.  Besides which I don't think `StringFormat` applies unless the target property being assigned to is demanding a `String` (for `DataGridTextColumn` this would be true).  Perhaps a) you should give it a go and b) include some more details of your xaml and code if it doesn't.